# How to dismiss bottom sheet programatically in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I have used a bottom sheet. I need to dismiss the attached bottom sheet in swift 5. I have used bellow code to the attached bottom sheet to viewController...

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dash_Board_Bottom_Sheet_Map") as! Dash_Board_Bottom_Sheet_Map
vc.attach(to: self)
```

Please help to dismiss bottom sheet

Comment: please share your attach() method code

Comment: @Manikandan  I have used UBottomSheet library. I have attached it to google map above code

Comment: https://github.com/OfTheWolf/UBottomSheet vc.detach()

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will work for you. This is for Remove the sheet from the current view controller.

```
vc.detach()
```